# named-checkzone fails reverse zone file with NS has no address records (A or AAAA)

Tags: dns, bind9

I'm setting up a private DNS server using bind9 on raspian.  I'm receiving this error on my reverse zone file:

```
root@dns:/etc/bind# named-checkzone dthacker.org db.dthacker.org.inv
    zone dthacker.org/IN: NS 'dns.dthacker.org' has no address records (A or          AAAA)
```

This is my reverse zone file:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA        dns.dthacker.org. root.dthacker.org. (
                        2015052003     ; Serial (NOTE: Needs to increment every time you restart BIND)
                        3600           ; Refresh [1h]
                        600            ; Retry   [10m]
                        86400          ; Expire  [1d]
                        600            ; Negative Cache TTL [1h]
                        )

        IN       NS      dns.dthacker.org.
30.1    IN      PTR      dns.dthacker.org.

61.1    IN      PTR      vhost.dthacker.org.
```

The forward file is passing without errors.  I can't see the error in this one.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using named-checkzone to check a reverse zone, you need to supply the reverse ip address to get a correct response from named-checkzone. Try this command:

```
named-checkzone 168.192.in-addr.arpa db.dthacker.org.inv
```

Change the IP adresses to your actual local network, and remember to reverse the numbers. My example assumes your machines have IP adresses `192.168.1.30` / `192.168.1.60`
Your reverse zone file is also missing an `ORIGIN` line. It is usually situated between the `$TTL` line and the `@   ...` line.
add this line:

```
 $ORIGIN     168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

and the db.dthacker.org.inv file should be OK.

All of this assumes that you have a functioning forward file for `dthacker.org`.